# Json object returning null against given key

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to read JSON from string (obtained from web), but it returns `null`.

Specifically, `result.append(name + id);` gives me `nullnull`

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {
    Object obj = parser.parse(datJ);
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
    Integer id = (Integer) jsonObject.get("id");
    result.append(name + id);

} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Consider that `datJ` contains following JSON string:

```
{
    "rikeard":{
        "id":2828822,
        "name":"Rikeard",
        "profileIconId":688,
        "summonerLevel":30,
        "revisionDate":1422917445000
    }
}
```

EDIT: Final code working

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            String datJ = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));
             Object obj = parser.parse(datJ);
                JSONObject rikeardObject = (JSONObject) ((Map<?, ?>) obj).get("rikeard");
                String name = (String) rikeardObject.get("name");
                Long id = (Long) rikeardObject.get("id");
```

**Special Thanks for Sufian and Ved!**

Comment: You just need to dig deeper into the object. `name` and `id` are within the `rikeard` key.

Comment: Which library are you using? Android's JSON or Jackson/Gson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"id" and "name" are inside the JSON object against the key "rikeard". So you need to make changes like following:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {
    Object obj = parser.parse(datJ);
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONObject rikeardObject = (JSONObject) obj.get("rikeard");
    String name = (String) rikeardObject.get("name");
    Integer id = (Integer) rikeardObject.get("id");
    result.append(name + id);

} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @Rikeard did this fix the problem? Ask me if you have any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {
      Object obj = parser.parse(datJ);
      JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONObject rikeardObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("rikeard");;
        String name = (String) rikeardObject .get("name");
        Integer id = (Integer) rikeardObject .get("id");
        result.append(name + id);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: he returns "The method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type Object"

Comment: He said "cannot convert from Object to JSONObject" when i put your code

Comment: You should parse your String properly in JSONObject. Try this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: "JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(datJ);"  Here it says the datJ need to be a map

Comment: if you are using json simple library then your code `JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;` returns outer json object. In this outer json object you have new Rikeard json object . Get this object first and then get the value as you want to access.

Comment: Now I have changed  my answer according to json simple library.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method it's work for me,

```
    private void extractJson(){
    String jsonString="{\"rikeard\":{\"id\":2828822,\"name\":\"Rikeard\",\"profileIconId\":688,\"summonerLevel\":30,\"revisionDate\":1422917445000}}";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonString);
        if(jsonObject!=null){
            jsonObject=jsonObject.optJSONObject("rikeard");
            if(jsonObject!=null){
                String id=jsonObject.optString("id");
                Log.d("MainActivity","id="+id);
            }
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```